# nvcc fatal : Value 'sm_86' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture'

Tags: cuda, blender

When I try to use CUDA with Blender 2.82.a+dfsg-1 I get the following error:

```
Compiling CUDA kernel ...
"nvcc" -arch=sm_86 --cubin "/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/source/kernel/kernels/cuda/kernel.cu" -o "/home/bram/.cache/cycles/kernels/cycles_kernel_sm86_673C3180FADE8EDF0E80E61994C4DC92.cubin" -m64 --ptxas-options="-v" --use_fast_math -DNVCC -I"/usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/cycles/source" 
nvcc fatal   : Value 'sm_86' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture'
CUDA kernel compilation failed, see console for details.
```

CUDA 11.1 is installed on my system, as is reported by nvidia-smi

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Sun Dec 20 19:34:48 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.38       Driver Version: 455.38       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 3070    Off  | 00000000:17:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   55C    P8    19W / 240W |    610MiB /  7979MiB |     12%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       968      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 59MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1598      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                247MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1749      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               74MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3855      G   ...e/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam       17MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3866      G   ./steamwebhelper                    3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3878      G   ...43331726878339,131072 --d       49MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5384      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5463      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5686      G   nvidia-settings                     3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9586      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9642      G   blender                           120MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9988      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I force blender to use a different shader-model? because apparently, it does not like **sm_86**.

Comment: seeing same problem on tensorflow1-gpu+ 3090 rtx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the allowed values for gpu-architecture with

```
nvcc --help
```

For my CUDA 10.1 install, I get:

```
Allowed values for this option:  'compute_30','compute_32','compute_35',
        'compute_37','compute_50','compute_52','compute_53','compute_60','compute_61',
        'compute_62','compute_70','compute_72','compute_75','sm_30','sm_32','sm_35',
        'sm_37','sm_50','sm_52','sm_53','sm_60','sm_61','sm_62','sm_70','sm_72',
        'sm_75'.
```

So sm_86 is not an allowed value.